# Swift 4 парсинг JSON по протоколу Decodable

Tags: json, ios, swift, swift4

Есть вот такая модель

```
class ItemGood: Decodable {
  var idServ: Int = 0
  var name: String?
  var image: String?
  var about: String?
  var price: Double = 0
  var idPartner: Int = 0
  var col: Int = 0
  var units: Int = 0
  var postage: Int = 0

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { // declaring our keys
    case name
    case image = "img_app"
    case about
    case price
    case idPartner = "id_Partner"
    case idServ = "id"
    case units = "id_unit"
    case postage
  }
}
```

Парсинг используется в нескольких местах. Проблема в том что в одном случае postage приходит, а во втором нет. Как сделать ключ postage не обязательным и избежать падения в случае без postage.

Comment: Делать опциональным. Я бы рекомендовал все делать опциональным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ItemGood: Decodable {
  var id_serv: Int = 0
  var name: String?
  var image: String?
  var about: String?
  var price: Double = 0
  var id_partner: Int = 0
  var col: Int = 0
  var units: Int = 0
  var postage: Int? = 0

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { // declaring our keys
    case name
    case image = "img_app"
    case about
    case price
    case id_partner
    case id_serv = "id"
    case units = "id_unit"
    case postage
  }
}
```